# CSS Animation for a counter

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a counter on my site that I am trying to animate similar to the text on http://liber.io/

I have the class

```
.flip-vertical
 transform: rotateX(180deg)
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg)
 -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg)
 -o-transform: rotateX(180deg)
 transition: 5.0s
 -webkit-transition: 5.0s
 -moz-transition: 5.3s
 -o-transition: 5.3s
 -ms-transition: 5.3s
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

https://jsfiddle.net/gnLmqsrm/

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any animation in the fiddle. Did you mean to say that the transform's output isn't as you want?

Comment: I don't see any flipping' text on that link.

Comment: @Harry yea, I am trying to mimic the transistion on liber.io

Comment: @jbutler483 look at the text after 'Right From'

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/gnLmqsrm/1/) where i've added a hover effect and added in the missing colons

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use CSS keyframes for this kind of implementation.

*Please note this is only a test, and timing may need to be improved. Also prefixes have been removed for simplicity (chrome supported in example).*

```css
.flip {
  position: relative;
}
.flip .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation: change 12s infinite;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.flip .child:first-child {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
.flip .child:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}
.flip .child:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">by</div>
  <div class="child">jbutler483</div>
</div>
```

---

Although I think js would be easier for this as It would allow you to alter the content much easier.

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var x = parseInt($('div').text()) + 1;
    $('div').text(x);
  }, 2000);


});
```

```css
.flip {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: swish 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes swish {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">1</div>
```